# Spring test No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/accueil] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

Hello I'm trying to test one of my class but I have this warning when i do `mvn test` : `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/accueil] in DispatcherServlet with name ''`.
This is strange because I have access to this page outside of the test.

here is the class that I want to test (I can access it via localhost:8080/accueil) :

```html
package uVote.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import uVote.DAO.ScrutinDAO;
import uVote.model.Scrutin;
import uVote.model.Votant;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/accueil")
public class Accueil
{
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String accueil(Model model,HttpServletRequest request)
 {  
     Votant co = VerifCo.isConnecte(request);
     if(co == null)
      return "redirect:connexion";
     else
     {
      request.setAttribute("votant", co);
      List<Scrutin> scrutins = new ScrutinDAO().getToutScrutins();
      List<Scrutin> scrutinsToShow = new ArrayList<Scrutin>();
      for(Scrutin s : scrutins)
      {
       if(!s.estDansRegistre(co) || s.isTermine())
        scrutinsToShow.add(s);
      }
      request.setAttribute("scrutins", scrutinsToShow);
     }
     return "accueil";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String deconnection(Model model,HttpServletRequest request)
 {
  VerifCo.deconnecteVotant(request);
  return "redirect:accueil";
 }

}
```

and here is the test case :

```html
package uVote.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import uVote.model.Votant;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = uVote.controllers.Accueil.class)
/**
 *
 * @author kirua
 */
public class AccueilTest
{
    
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    
    @Before
    public void setup() 
    {
        DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
        this.mockMvc = builder.build();
 
 InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/vues/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
 
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HelpController())
                                 .setViewResolvers(viewResolver)
                                 .build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testVotant() throws Exception 
    {
 HashMap<String, Object> sessionattr = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Votant vo = new Votant(1, "toto_prenom", "toto_nom", "toto_adresse", "mdp");
 sessionattr.put("votant", vo);
       
 ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();
// ResultMatcher msg = MockMvcResultMatchers.model()
  //                         .attribute("msg", "Spring quick start!!");

 MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/accueil").sessionAttrs(sessionattr);
 this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
      .andExpect(ok)
      .andExpect(view().name("accueil"));
//                   .andExpect(msg);
    }
}
```

and the HelpController :

```html
public class HelpController extends AbstractController
{

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelpController.class);
    
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception
    {
 log.debug("Entering HelpController.handleRenderRequestInternal()");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Help");
        log.debug("Exiting HelpController.handleRenderRequestInternal() " + modelAndView);
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
}
```

my web.xml :

```html
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
</web-app>
```

my servlet-context.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
 <!-- Anable du model @Controller -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Gère les requète d'éléments de ressource (css / js / images ...) -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Résolution des vues utilisées (renvoyées) par les controller - Rendu/Intepretation JSP -->
 <beans:bean id="viewReslover" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<!--                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/> -->
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/vues/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

 
 <context:component-scan base-package="uVote.controllers" />
 
</beans:beans>
```

and my root-context :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  
</beans>
```

Do you have an idea of what is happening ? I'm a noob in java so I'm not sure where could be the problem.
Please ask if you need to see some other file.

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Comment: I have edited my post to add it.

Comment: Pls add /WEB-INF/root-context.xml  and /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml also.

Comment: i have added it in my post.